# What is a "shooting jacket"?

Tags: terminology, shooting

I read this news report today about a [Malaysian competitor in the commonwealth games](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/shooting/28418330).

> Commonwealth shooting champion Nur Ayuni Farhana Abdul Halim will be
>   unable to compete in Glasgow after her competition jacket went
>   missing.... "The rules clearly state that a rifle shooter must wear a
>   jacket. "We tried to borrow one but it did not fit her. We tried to
>   make a new one but she said that she would need two months to get
>   used to it."

This begged the question, what on earth is a shooting jacket? Why do you need one and why would it "need two months to get used to it"???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to: [*Competition Shooting 101: CMP/NRA High Power* By Nick Leghorn on April 21, 2011](http://www.thetruthaboutguns.com/2011/04/foghorn/competition-shooting-101-cmpnra-high-power/)

> **Shooting Jacket** – This is another tool for keeping you steady. While standing or sitting, having an extremely tight jacket to hold
>   you up can be a real help. It also helps keep the sling in proper
>   position during prone. It’s a little spend-y, but worth the expense.

[Creedmoor Sports](http://www.creedmoorsports.com/shop/World_Famous_Shooting_Coats/) says:

> Creedmoor’s world famous shooting coats deliver advantageous support
>   for the shooters standing position. Wearing a Creedmoor shooting coat
>   every time provides the consistency necessary to achieve better
>   performance.  Not only will a Creedmoor shooting coat improve scores,
>   but utilizing a high-quality Creedmoor shooting coat will add comfort
>   during a competition.

Comment: Interesting, explains what one is. Seems odd that you *must* have one to compete. Surely not having one is simply a disadvantage. I wondered if it was also a safety thing?

Comment: @Liam Perhaps it's a pride thing; if you know you can't perform to your potential don't compete at all?

Comment: No, it explicitly said *The rules clearly state that a rifle shooter must wear a jacket*? TBF, I wanted to know what one was primarily which you've answered.

Comment: The rules state that you must have one, and what type of jacket it is. This helps ensure consistency between athletes - basically it is just one of the rules of the game.

Comment: Presumably a high-tech jacket could provide advantages and thus limits must be set lest the swimsuit debacle repeat

Comment: @WW. Shooting sports 2044: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yp0h8.jpg